# What do the exclamation point icons mean?

Tags: grid-2

I keep seeing these in the multiplayer, but I'm not sure what they actually are. I've assumed so far that they are to do with the players connection status, but I've no evidence to back that up.

Does anyone know what they actually mean?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this](http://community.codemasters.com/t5/GRID-2-General-Discussion/Multiplayer-exclamation-points/td-p/263438) thread it is believed to be the new impact rating which you can use to filter games on too. Here is the most helpful part of that forum that summaries their useage:

> Just to confirm what others have said, it's the impact rating system.
>
> Basically once the game has accessed how you drive it will then assign a rating to you, green is for clean racing, red is for rough.
>
> The matchmaking system will then look at placing you in games with players of the same impact rating as yourself. This means that if you like clean racing you can avoid those who like the rough stuff and vice versa.

By impact rating they presumably mean how much you crash and ram other players.

Comment: This is great news. I do get quite frustrated by people bashing into me at corners.